# Suggested Edit rejected with an almost identical edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9690298), which slightly improved the grammar of the question and replaced an irrelevant tag with one that was applicable.

The edit was rejected by the Community user with the message:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

And was then [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32856950/revisions) to almost exactly the same as my suggestion (instead of the word "After" the editor used "Upon", added a comma, and replaced a dash with a colon) except for the fact that the tags were not modified (which, in my opinion, was the most important part of my edit).

So, my question is, what exactly were the critical issues I didn't correct but the final revision did?  Is this because I changed the tags?  Am I just looking at the revision incorrectly? (Admittedly I don't see them often so I might be missing something obvious)

Comment: _"After sanitizing the \`src` attribute is not included in the sanitized html."_ isn't clear at all. Try reading that aloud.  _"Upon sanitizing, the \`src` attribute is not included in the sanitized html."_ is the appropriate fix, the comma and the word change indicate the src attribute isn't included in the html once it's sanitized.

Comment: I'd say at best your suggestion was "no improvement" and should have been rejected anyway.  As Trobbins pointed out, the reviewer actually made the post clearly understandable.  That comma is really important in parsing the sentence into distinct parts.

Comment: Ah I understand, should've read that sentence out loud I guess.  I was mainly concerned about the tags, probably why I missed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit was "reject and edit" which should be read as:

"your change did not meet review bar even if it *could* be useful. Please avoid minor/incomplete changes till you get to 2K".

In general tag changes are considered minor and likely will be made quickly by someone with 2K complete edit privileges anyway. I'd not worry too much about misplaced tags as long as question gets attention till you get to 2k and can edit without review. One case where tag-only (or close to it) edit would be ok as "suggested edit" is if OP made completely invalid low traffic tag choices essentially making post invisible for most  viewers (i.e. "batch-file" for Java question) - would need clear comment why it is useful.